# GLFW - Vulkan not supported

Tags: 3d, glfw, vulkan

I've been following the Vulkan tutorial at https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ and I've been having issues with the section on [setting up the window surface](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Presentation/Window_surface). Upon completing the section and testing nothing had broken, I found I was getting an error on the following GLFW call:

`glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface);`

It was returning -3. A quick bit of research revealed this was the error for `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`, which I then discovered meant the Vulkan loader was not being found. Upon testing, sure enough, I found that `glfwVulkanSupported()` was returning `GLFW_FALSE`. However, I cannot figure out why. I am using the LunarG Vulkan SDK 1.0.65.1, from [here](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/), and x64 GLFW 3.2.1 from [here](http://www.glfw.org/download.html). As far as I can tell, this should be working; searching the web gives no useful results. Vulkan programs such as `cube.exe`, which comes with the SDK, work fine.

Thanks :)

Code:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <set>
#include <string>

VkResult CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(
        VkInstance instance,
        const VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT *pCreateInfo,
        const VkAllocationCallbacks *pAllocator,
        VkDebugReportCallbackEXT *pCallback){
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (func != nullptr){
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pCallback);
    }
    else{
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}

void DestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT(
        VkInstance instance,
        VkDebugReportCallbackEXT callback,
        const VkAllocationCallbacks *pAllocator){
    auto func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (func != nullptr){
        func(instance, callback, pAllocator);
    }
}

struct QueueFamilyIndices {
    int graphicsFamily = -1;
    int presentFamily = -1;
    bool isComplete() {
        return graphicsFamily >= 0 && presentFamily >= 0;
    }
};


class CraftmineApplication {
    public:
        void run(){
            initVulkan();
            initWindow();
            mainLoop();
            cleanup();
        }

    private:
        GLFWwindow *window;
        VkInstance instance;
        VkDebugReportCallbackEXT callback;
        VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        VkDevice device;
        VkQueue graphicsQueue;
        VkSurfaceKHR surface;
        VkQueue presentQueue;

        const int WIDTH = 1920;
        const int HEIGHT = 1080;

        const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
            "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
        };

#ifdef NDEBUG
        const bool enableValidationLayers = false;
#else
        const bool enableValidationLayers = true;
#endif

        static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
                VkDebugReportFlagsEXT flags,
                VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objType,
                uint64_t obj,
                size_t location,
                int32_t code,
                const char *layerPrefix,
                const char *msg,
                void *userData){
            std::cerr << "Validation layer: " << msg << std::endl;

            return VK_FALSE;
        }

        QueueFamilyIndices findQueueFamilies(VkPhysicalDevice device) {
            QueueFamilyIndices indices;
            uint32_t queueFamilyCount = 0;
            vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &queueFamilyCount, nullptr);

            std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queueFamilies(queueFamilyCount);
            vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &queueFamilyCount, queueFamilies.data());

            int i = 0;
            for (const auto &queueFamily : queueFamilies) {
                VkBool32 presentSupport = false;
                vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(device, i, surface, &presentSupport);

                if (queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) {
                    indices.graphicsFamily = i;
                }

                if (queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && presentSupport) {
                    indices.presentFamily = i;
                }

                if (indices.isComplete()) {
                    break;
                }

                i++;
            }

            return indices;
        }

        void createInstance(){
            if (enableValidationLayers && !checkValidationLayerSupport())
                throw std::runtime_error("Validation layers requested, but not available!");

            VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
            appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
            appInfo.pApplicationName = "Craftmine";
            appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
            appInfo.pEngineName = "";
            appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
            appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

            VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
            createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
            createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

            if (enableValidationLayers){
                createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
                createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
            }
            else{
                createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
            }

            auto extensions = getRequriedExtensions();

            createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
            createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

            uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
            vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);
            std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> vulkan_extensions(extensionCount);
            vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, vulkan_extensions.data());

            bool extensionsPresent = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < extensions.size(); i++) {
                const char *extNeeded = extensions[i];
                bool found = false;
                for (const VkExtensionProperties &extension : vulkan_extensions){
                    if(!strcmp(extNeeded,extension.extensionName)){
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!found){
                    extensionsPresent = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!extensionsPresent)
                throw std::runtime_error("Not all required window extensions present!");


            if(vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create instance!");
        }

        void initWindow(){
            glfwInit();

            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

            window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Craftmine", nullptr, nullptr);
        }

        void initVulkan(){
            createInstance();
            setupDebugCallback();
            createSurface();
            pickPhysicalDevice();
            createLogicalDevice();
        }

        void createSurface() {
            if(glfwVulkanSupported() != GLFW_TRUE) throw std::runtime_error("No Vulkan!");
            if (glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface) != VK_SUCCESS)
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window surface!");

        }

        void createLogicalDevice() {
            QueueFamilyIndices indices = findQueueFamilies(physicalDevice);

            std::vector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo> queueCreateInfos;
            std::set<int> uniqueQueueFamilies = { indices.graphicsFamily, indices.presentFamily };

            float queuePriority = 1.0f;

            for (int queueFamily : uniqueQueueFamilies) {
                VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueCreateInfo = {};
                queueCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
                queueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = queueFamily;
                queueCreateInfo.queueCount = 1;
                queueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority;
                queueCreateInfos.push_back(queueCreateInfo);
            }

            VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures = {};

            VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
            createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;

            createInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = queueCreateInfos.data();
            createInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(queueCreateInfos.size());

            createInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures;

            createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;

            if (enableValidationLayers) {
                createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
                createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
            }
            else {
                createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
            }

            if (vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, &createInfo, nullptr, &device) != VK_SUCCESS) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create logical device!");
            }

            vkGetDeviceQueue(device, indices.graphicsFamily, 0, &graphicsQueue);
            vkGetDeviceQueue(device, indices.presentFamily, 0, &presentQueue);
        }

        void pickPhysicalDevice() {
            uint32_t deviceCount = 0;
            vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, nullptr);
            if (deviceCount == 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find GPUs with Vulkan support!");

            std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> devices(deviceCount);
            vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, devices.data());

            int currentMaxScore = 0;
            for (const auto &device : devices) {
                if (getDeviceScore(device) > currentMaxScore) {
                    physicalDevice = device;
                }
            }

            if (physicalDevice == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find a suitable GPU!");
            }
        }

        int getDeviceScore(VkPhysicalDevice device) {
            VkPhysicalDeviceProperties deviceProperties;
            VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures;
            vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(device, &deviceProperties);
            vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(device, &deviceFeatures);

            QueueFamilyIndices indices = findQueueFamilies(device);

            if (!indices.isComplete()) return 0;

            int score = 1;
            score += deviceProperties.deviceType == VK_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_DISCRETE_GPU;
            // If unsuitable return 0

            return score;
        }

        void setupDebugCallback(){
            if (!enableValidationLayers) return;

            VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT createInfo = {};
            createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
            createInfo.flags = VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT;
            createInfo.pfnCallback = debugCallback;

            if(CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(instance, &createInfo, nullptr, &callback) != VK_SUCCESS){
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set up debug callback!");
            }
        }

        void mainLoop(){
            while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
                glfwPollEvents();
            }
        }

        void cleanup(){
            vkDestroyDevice(device, nullptr);
            DestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT(instance, callback, nullptr);
            vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, nullptr);
            vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            glfwTerminate();
        }

        bool checkValidationLayerSupport(){
            uint32_t layerCount;
            vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

            std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
            vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

            for (const char *layerName : validationLayers){
                bool layerFound = false;

                for (const VkLayerProperties &layerProperties : availableLayers){
                    if (!strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName)){
                        layerFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!layerFound)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        std::vector<const char*> getRequriedExtensions() {
            uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
            const char** glfwExtensions;
            glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

            std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount);

            if (enableValidationLayers){
                extensions.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME);
            }

            return extensions;
        }
};

int main(){
    CraftmineApplication app;

    try{
        app.run();
    }catch(const std::runtime_error &e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Try setting a GLFW error callback and check the error description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `glfwInit` before checking Vulkan compatibility. That is, in `void run()` call `initWindow()` before `initVulkan()`.